# Why does adb install fail from context menu with "must specify a apk size" error?

Tags: android, registry, adb, windows-shell

I have manually added a .apk and apkfile entry to my registry under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\` with the following keys:

```
apkfile
  shell
    Install to Device
      command = "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" install /r "%1"
```

This successfully adds a context menu item called Install to Device that appears to successfully run over the file.

The command prompt opens and closes with these messages:

> Performing Streamed Install
>
> adb: failed to install C:[path][myapk].apk: Error: must specify a APK size

However, Running the (apparently) same command over the APK in cmd or powershell succeeds.

Any idea why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but eventually I realized that I was trying to install multiple apk's, so I removed the others and kept only one apk.

Answer (score 0):

In your command instead of using /r, try using - r. I hope that helps